# Shouldn't Naruto's RasenShuriken be a forbidden Jutsu if it's so powerful?

Tags: naruto

Naruto's RasenShuriken can usually kill average shinobi in one shot. If it's so powerful shouldn't it be forbidden?

Comment: For the close voter. Could elaborate why you found this to be Opinion based? This question, to me, seems as if it could be answered through in-universe facts.

Answer (score 10):

It's not typical of strong techniques to be forbidden. Forbidden jutsu are often techniques that either damage the user, require a sacrifice (other than just Chakra), or is generally immoral.

Incidentally, Tsunade did declare Fuuton: Rasenshuriken as a forbidden jutsu after seeing the damage it caused Naruto's arm. Whether or not it's still forbidden after Naruto perfected it and managed to throw it (thus, nullifying the damage to himself).

Other examples of forbidden jutsu:

- Izanagi - Because it sacrifices an eye.
- Tajuu Kage Bunshin (Massive Shadow Clone) - Because the user might die from chakra loss
- Edo Tensei - Because of living sacrifice and immorality.

Comment: Forbidden techiques where the cost is exclusively on the user, like Kage bunshin, the Gates and Primary Lotus, are never really punished or even cared about by the higher ups. Forbidden is more like Taboo, Learn at your own risk, and be prepared to face the concequences. Ones like Edo Tensei would probably be heavily punished by authority, but no one seems to care to stop Lee or Naruto from using their techniques despite them being forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

Because it destroys the cell that produces chakra not only to the one hit by it but also to the user which is naruto . That's why it's forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Like the first guy said Tsunade did mark it as forbidden jutsu but when Naruto learns sage mode and then Bijuu mode he uses it because it no longer damages him.

Answer (score 0):

It is a forbidden jutsu. Later on Naruto learns to use Sage Art: Rasenshuriken which lets him throw it by applying nature chakra to maintain it's shape, but I think this is classified separately. Outside that, he can use chakra arms of his nine tails chakra mode to guide them, also negating the damage done to him. But, anyone who doesn't know senjutus or has a tail beast chakra mode will still be at risk, since it then has to be used as a melee jutsu.

Answer (score 0):

It was originally classified as a forbiden jutsu because of the damage it can cause to the user.

> "The name is a bit of a misnomer. The jutsu works like a poison. It causes damage to the cells that produce chakra. Even those of the user. If Naruto continues to  use that ninjutsu he will lose the ability to mold chakra."
>   - Fith Hokage, Sanin, Slug sage, Medical Sage Tsunade Senju

But when he throws it, it nullifies the damage to himself. So I suppose it was deforbiden.